# Ошибка на нулевой строке PHP (Можно ли отловить?)

Tags: php

Приветствую Всех!
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
В .htaccess указал опцию `php_value max_file_uploads 3`
Так вот, если пользователь будет загружать больше 3 файлов, то PHP выдает ошибку следующего характера:

Warning:  Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded in Unknown on line 0

Возможно ли отловить подобную ошибку, если да, то как это можно сделать? Куда копать?

Или на подобные ошибки нужно закрывать глаза запретив отображать ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем правильно показывать пользователям ошибки! Посмотрите в сторону `display_errors`. Кроме того, лучше реализовать проверку количества загружаемых файлов на уровне принимающего скрипта.

Таким образом — на ошибки можно забить при условии контроля на уровне кода PHP; Ошибку, если она действительно warning, можно игнорировать.

Чтобы получить более полный ответ, приведите часть кода и описание системы.

Comment: Разумеется, в коде PHP осуществляется проверка на всевозможные ошибки. Если реализовать проверку ТОЛЬКО в самом скрипте, то, во-первых, пользователю придется ждать пока все файлы (к примеру 20 файлов из 3) будут загружены, а это лишний трафик, а это лишнее время, лишняя обработка. Во-вторых, подобная ошибка все равно может вылететь, если стоит ограничение на количество передаваемых байт, а такое ограничение будет, как в принимающем файле, так и не в нем, поэтому в любом случае эти ошибки нужно отлавливать. Нельзя же просо запретить их отображать через `display_errors`?

Comment: POST запрос с содержимым файлов все-равно придет к PHP в количестве, которое отправит пользователь. Если их будет 20, то 20 файлов и поступит "трафиком" на сервер. Это в любом случае произойдет, даже если в php.ini запретить такое количество. Интерпретатор начинает работать только при получении запроса.

Comment: @pan-ili-propal Проблема этой конкретно ошибки в том, что она выскакивает еще перед выполнением вашего скрипта, т.е. перед запуском runtime. Такую ошибку можно отключить, как и все ошибки в продакшене, однако правильнее будет ограничить количество передаваемых файлов на клиенте.

Comment: Я понял, значит такие ошибки просто скрывать нужно. В таком случае лучше ограничить число передаваемых байт до runtime, а количество передаваемых файлов ограничить в принимающем скрипте, верно? Или другая схема решения подобного недуга имеется?)

Comment: Это не недуг. На production не используется вывод ошибок на экран, только в логи. В Вашем случае, процесс загрузки нужно контролировать с двух сторон: сервер (скрипт php на сервере) и клиент (GUI, которым пользуется юзер). Если у Вас на стороне клиента используется html страница, ограничьте количество полей <input type='file'....